# Cannot delete picture

Tags: ios, arrays, save

I am saving my pictures into the collection view but I cannot delete the picture that I have took. I am using tap delete in the collection view.  This is my code for that.However after I tap and delete the picture it looks like the picture is not deleted, and cannot find where is wrong,  I am suspecting that it has something to do with the array but I am not sure.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *locations = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Bottoms", @"Dress", @"Coats", @"Others", @"hats", @"Tops",nil ];
    NSString *fPath = documentsDirectory;
    NSMutableArray *trashCan = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *directoryContent;
    for(NSString *component in locations){
    NSString *TrashBin = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:component];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: TrashBin];
    collectionTrash.delegate =self;
    collectionTrash.dataSource=self;
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
    NSLog(@"str:%@", str);
  NSString *finalFilePath = [TrashBin stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
        [trashCan addObject:finalFilePath];
        if(data)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [allImagesArray addObject:image];
            NSLog(@"array:%@",[allImagesArray description]);

        }}}
    Trash = trashCan;
    for(NSString *folder in locations) {

    for(NSString *file in directoryContent) {

            // load the image

        }
    }}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    NSLog(@"j");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [allImagesArray count];


}



-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reuseID = @"ReuseID";
    TrashCell *mycell = (TrashCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageInCell = (UIImageView*)[mycell viewWithTag:1];
    imageInCell.image = [allImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"a");
    return mycell;
}    
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"s:%d", [Trash count]);
    NSString *trashBin = [Trash objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"k%@l",trashBin);
    [allImagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.collectionTrash reloadData];
    [self deleteMyFiles:trashBin];
}
NSString *myFileName;
-(void) deleteMyFiles:(NSString*)filePath {
    NSError *error;

       if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you delete the image in local memory also. When you delete image from collectionView not delete. Then stop the app and run it again see the deleted image is removed or not?. I think this is your problem. Then store all the image in single array and store it in plist. When you remove any image replace the array after removing the image in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[collectionView reloadData]
```

after calling `deleteMyFiles`.